# Why is $O(n^{km}+n^m)=O(n^{km})$?

Tags: computational-complexity

I've seen this equation in one of my handouts $O(n^{km}+n^m)=O(n^{km})$, which doesn't seem obvious to me.

This is what I got trying to work it out:

$$\begin{align*}n^{km}+n^m &\leq C \cdot n^{km}\\
\frac{n^{km}+n^m}{n^{km}}&\leq C \\
1+\frac{n^m}{n^{km}} &\leq C\\
1+n^{m(1-k)} &\leq C\\
\end{align*}$$

But how can a constant be bigger than a polynomial?

Comment: Because $x^m=O(x^{km})$ (I suppose $k\ge 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming positive integral powers, then $k\geq1$, hence $1-k\leq0$, so that $$1+n^{m(1-k)}\leq2$$ for sufficiently large $n$.